# Reading csv file which include two double quotes inside quote and line breaks

Tags: python, file, csv, dataframe

I've got a problem that I have a big file which I want to read in Python and it looks like:

```
"2019-10-09 10:11:09","NICK","Hello, how are you
today? I'm like ""weather"", often changing."
```

I want to read this file into dataframe that will looks like:

```
col1                  col2          col3
2019-10-09 09:32:09   NICK          Hello, how are you today? I'm like ""weather"", often changing.
```

I've got few problems with it. First of all, there is a problem, that my separator is ',' which is also inside some messages from col3. Second problem is that inside some messages from col3 there is line break which I don't know how to handle (as in the example after 'you'). And the last problem is that inside the messages from col3 there is also two double quotes '""""' which are representing a quote inside the message.

I've tried to read this file with:

```
with open('/data/myfile.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
    df = pd.read_csv(csvfile, sep=",", quotechar='"', escapechar='\\')
```

Unfortunately, this method is not working. I don't know which from this three things which I explained is causing the problem. It showing me errors that it expected three columns but there was few more.

EDIT:
There is some other problem, because it still shows me this error:

`Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 3 fields in line 60, saw 5`

When I look at the file I don't know how it's interpreting lines, because I've got in messages from col3 some break lines inside. How can i print this exact line which is causing problem?

EDIT2:
I've used this code in terminal:

```
sed -n 60p myfile.csv
```

And it printed empty line. So I I did it also with lines few lines before and after. It looks like:

```
"2019-10-09 10:11:09","som1","This isn't this.
It's like this, and this.

And as my opinions is this.

Finally, it's the end."
```

EDIT3:
@Boendal was right. This line which I've included is not causing the problem. Now I've edited code to:

```
with open('opinions-ml.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
    df = pd.read_csv(csvfile, names=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'], sep=",", quotechar='"', escapechar='\\')
```

And I found that problem is caused by rows like that:

```
"2019-10-09 10:11:09","NICK","This is some text "and this, is quote" and it is also text
Awww. and, there was, line break"
```

Python is reading this as dataframe which looks like:

```
col1                  col2          col3
2019-10-09 09:32:09   NICK          This is some text and this
Awww. and             there was     line break
```

Do you think that there is a chance to do something with this problem? Maybe using regex? Or should I get back to file provider to fix that?

EDIT4:
And another line:

```
"2019-10-09 10:11:09","NICK","This is some text "and this is quote" and it is also text
Awww. and there, was line break"
```

Python is reading this as dataframe which looks like:

```
col1                  col2            col3
2019-10-09 09:32:09   NICK            This is some text and this is quote" and it is also text
Awww. and there       was line break  NaN
```

Comment: your problem is that `""weather""` is not escaped and pandas think it is a quotechar. If you would change this to `\"\"weather\"\"` it would work (you specify escapechar with `\\`. I think you have to do some preprocessing before loading it into panda

Comment: @Boendal, Do you think that this preprocessing is possible to do with Python?

Comment: See my answer maybe it helps you.

Comment: print the line that causing you problem in your question instead of asking where to print.

Comment: @Boendal, How can I print this exact line which is causing problem? When I open this file in terminal, I don't know how to count lines where are line breaks in the messages (so in some lines there is only parts from `col3`).

Comment: There are 2 ways: Upload your whole file somewhere or delete lines until the problem doesn't appear anymore => the last line deleted is the problem line.

Comment: this line is not a problem works for me.

Comment: See my updated answer, this line doesn't cause me a problem.

Comment: and line 60 means the 60th row of data not the 60th line in your file.

Comment: @Boendal, you were right. I've edited my question.

Comment: As I told you I think that single quotes are more dangerous than double quote. Now you have a problem. It is quite hard to preprocess this. Basically your data is quite corrupt. But yeah you have to change `"` to `\"` somehow.

Comment: I will try to get file with all quotes inside message marked with two ". I hope that your solution from answer will work after that.

Comment: You don't even need my code if you can transform all quotes inside the message into `\"` this would fix everything.

Answer (score 2):

According to me csv dialect can be helpful.
following code produces correct output.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

csv.register_dialect('mydialect', delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, doublequote=True)
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', dialect='mydialect')
df
```

Solution-2: Reformat data

- first 2 columns does not need any processing.
- third column need to be escaped.
- split the line by , (comma) and escape value from third index.

  ```
  import csv
  with open('test.csv') as infile, open('reformated_data.csv', 'w', newline='') as outfile:

      outputWriter = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter=',',
                              escapechar='\\', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
      for line in infile:
          line = line.split(',')
          col12 = line[0:2]
          col3 = ''.join(line[2:]).encode("unicode_escape").decode("utf-8")
          outputWriter.writerow(col12 + [col3])
  ```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html
https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#dialects-and-formatting-parameters

Comment: It still doesn't work for me. It produces error 
`Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 7 fields in line 60, saw 9`
Probably, in some message there is double line break.

Comment: You can also provide `lineterminator` in dialect as per your file.(check these \r,\n,\r\n)

Comment: There is another option of `error_bad_lines=False` in pd.read_csv which will drop bad lines from data.

Comment: I know about skipping lines, but it skipping around 3k lines from my file, so it's a lot. (total number is 150k). And with `lineterminator` it still shows the same error

Comment: I think you need to format data before processing, I provided solution-2 in my answer, that may help.

Answer (score 0):

As I told you in the comment your problem is that in `""weather""` the `"` are not escaped. Therefore pandas interpret it as quotechar. As far as I am aware of there is not some way to prevent that escaped to preprocess your file and change `""weaterh""`into `\"\"weather\"\"`.

One way you can do that is:

```
with open('/data/myfile.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f_in, open("/data/preprocessed.csv", 'w') as f_out:
    for line in f_in:
        line = line.replace('""', '\\\"\\\"')
        f_out.write(line)
```

This change

```
"2019-10-09 10:11:09","NICK","Hello, how are you
today? I'm like ""weather"", often changing."
"2019-10-09 10:11:09","som1","This isn't this.
It's like this, and this.

And as my opinions is this.

Finally, it's the end."
```

to

```
"2019-10-09 10:11:09","NICK","Hello, how are you
today? I'm like \"\"weather\"\", often changing."
"2019-10-09 10:11:09","som1","This isn't this.
It's like this, and this.

And as my opinions is this.

Finally, it's the end."
```

Then you can create a dataframe with it (with the code you posted above and with the new created file) and it would look like this:

```
                  col1  col2                                                                                                  col3
0  2019-10-09 10:11:09  NICK                                      Hello, how are you\ntoday? I'm like ""weather"", often changing.
1  2019-10-09 10:11:09  som1  This isn't this.\nIt's like this, and this.\n\nAnd as my opinions is this.\n\nFinally, it's the end.
```

You only posted one row of data, there may be other errors you are unaware of. I think single quotes in your data may be a bigger problem than double quotes but try it out and see how it goes.

Comment: So it's like you said, there is some other problem, because it still shows me this error: `Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 7 fields in line 60, saw 9`  When I look at the file I don't know how it's interpreting lines, because I've got in messages from `col3` some break lines inside. Can i print somehow this exact line which is causing problem?

Comment: @maliniaki post it in your question.

Comment: Ok I did. Also it shows `Expected 3 fields` - not as I've mentioned 7

Comment: @maliniaki we don't know how your data looks like so you have to provide us with more information/data so we can help you. We can't guess your problem with only that.